# "Проси у меня (,) чего хочешь" — цельное по смыслу выражение?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, цельное-выражение

У Розенталя встречаются похожие выражения:
делай что хочешь, зови кого хочешь, дать чего не жалко, наслушаться чего не надо.

Из этого ли разряда данный пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно читаем Розенталя.

> [§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)
>   Цельные по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.<...>
>   Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен члену предложения.
>   Так, в сочетании *говорит об этом **где только может*** выделенные слова имеют значение "везде".

По-моему, у нас именно такой случай (проси любое). А чтобы развеять все сомнения, читаем дальше:

> Выражения с глаголом хотеть, образующие цельные по смыслу выражения, запятой не разделяются: пиши как хочешь ("пиши по-всякому"); над ним командует кто хочет; его не гоняет только кто не хочет; приходи когда хочешь; бери сколько хочешь; гуляй с кем хочешь; делай что хочешь; распоряжайтесь как хотите; напишет какую хочешь статью; выпьет какое хочешь вино; женись на ком хочешь.