# Необходимы ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. Знаешь кому я нужен?
2. Он лезет куда не следует.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437845/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Знаешь, кому я нужен?** Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.

**Он лезет куда не следует.** Это устойчивый оборот с подчинительным союзом (не отделяется запятой).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

**Лезть/не лезть  куда не следует** и т.д.